# Pass an array of values as post data to document.forms[].method?

Tags: php, javascript

In my html I have this,

```
    <tr>
        <td class="grid_cell" width="5%">
            <input type="checkbox" name="workspace_trees_rpt_target" id="<?php echo $t["tree_id"];?>" value="<?php echo $t["tree_id"];?>" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

this are inside a loop so what will be displayed is a lot of checkboxes with different values. And in my script I have this,

```
    if(confirm("Delete cannot be undone, click OK button to proceed.")) {
        document.forms[0].method="POST";
        document.forms[0].action="delete.php";
        document.forms[0].submit();     
    }
```

after selecting two of the checkboxes and click the OK button, I then go to `delete.php` to `print_r` my post data. But when the result of `print_r` is displayed it only showed one value for the checked checkboxes, but I was expecting two of them. How can I make it such that when I check multiple checkboxes, the post data for the checkboxes will be an array of values of the checked checkboxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must set the name of the inputs as array:

```
name="workspace_trees_rpt_target[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the same name to all of your checkboxes. So only one value can be returned.

Change to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="workspace_trees_rpt_target[]" id="<?php echo $t["tree_id"];?>" value="<?php echo $t["tree_id"];?>" />
```

Then in your PHP code you will get and array of $_POST['workspace_trees_rpt_target'][]

So process it like this:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['workspace_trees_rpt_target'] ) ) {
    // at least one checkbox has been ticked
    foreach ( $_POST['workspace_trees_rpt_target']  as $checkboxe ) {
         // do whatever $checkbox it will be set to the value="" that you set earlier
    }
}
```